# RTL8723BE Linux driver no longer works for any 5.x kernel and the lwfinger Github repository that had the drivers doesn't exist anymore

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, wifi-driver

All in the title. I'm running Mint 20 Xfce with the older 4.15.109 kernel since that's the only one that supports my wifi adapter, this is my hardware setup -

```
System:    Kernel: 4.15.0-109-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana 
           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 80C1 v: 96.31 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.11 date: 07/23/2015 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 35.5 Wh condition: 35.5/41.6 Wh (85%) model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-5200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 17557 
           Speed: 897 MHz min/max: 500/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 898 2: 898 3: 898 4: 898 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-109-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 
           bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtl8723be v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 0d:00.0 
           IF: wlp13s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 159.29 GiB (34.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050A7E680 size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 453.26 GiB used: 129.10 GiB (28.5%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: /home size: 453.26 GiB used: 129.10 GiB (28.5%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 12.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 39.5 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 255 Uptime: 28m Memory: 11.64 GiB used: 2.25 GiB (19.3%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           clang: 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

This is `lwconfig` for my 4.15.109 kernel -

```
wlp13s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"mySSID"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 34:E8:94:66:C5:B6   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:40391   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

...and this is what I get when I boot into 5.4.0.45 (the latest) -

```
wlp13s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
```

Everywhere I've searched see references to the [lwfinger](https://github.com/lwfinger/) repository on Github, but the specific subproject for RTL8723BE throws a 404.

Is there a way to get my adapter to work with a 5.x kernel or am I stuck on 4.15.109 forever?

Comment: I am confused... rtl8723be has been in the standard kernel for a few years, that is why support for it was discontinued on lwfinger repo, I don't get a 404 message, I get "This repo is obsolete. Use the driver in the kernel, or the one in the Backports Project." from this link: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be Are you sure you don't have the stock kernel driver blacklisted since you used a 3rd party one before? Does the wireless work if you just boot the live USB for LM20?

Comment: No, never worked whether on live USB or regular install. I upgraded from 19.3 and it upgraded my kernel as well - then I found that it doesn't work with any version 5 kernel after trying all the older ones that were there.